# Convert lines to different Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a .txt file with lines (in my situation 2). I need to read lines and convert each to a different Array. Ex:
1 line - A,B,C
2 line - D,E,F,G, etc.

and convert this to:
[A,B,C]
[D,E,F,G]

I'm doing this with String.split(", ")

```
ArrayList<String> al_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
while(true){
    String[] line = rbuff.readLine().split(",");
    for(String i : line){
        al_1.add(i);
    }
    if(line == null) break;
}
```

What's the best way to fill the second?
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you must use

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<String> al_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> al_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and fullfill this list with **al.add()**

Comment: @JohnGray That *is* two `ArrayLists`.

Comment: This case you must rbuff.readLine() again, check agains null, split it and fill second array, but your use case is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

IMO easier to keep a list of lists.

```
List<List<String>> lineLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

while (true) {
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] line = rbuff.readLine().split(",");
    for (String i : line) {
        lineList.add(i);
    }
    lineLists.add(lineList);
    if (line == null) break;
}
```

(Ignoring that there are any number of ways to split immediately into an array or list w/o the inner loop. Either way, the inner loop should be refactored.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will allow you to add a new ArrayList to the myArrayList for each row your read of your file:

```
            List<List<String>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<String> myStrings;
            while (true) {
                myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
                String[] line = rbuff.readLine().split(",");
                for (String i : line) {
                    myStrings.add(i);
                }
                myArrayList.add(myStrings);
                if (line == null)
                    break;
            }
```

You will have a List with one List inside for each row of your text file.

```
MyArrayList
|
|_____List('A', 'B', 'C')
|
|_____List('D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
|
|_____(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that's pretty much what I'd do, but with the mention that if you don't need your lines to inside ArrayList objects, you can use array Strings (String[]). Here's an example:

```
private static String s1 = "A,B,C",s2="D,E,F";
    private static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(){{add(s1);add(s2);}};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<Integer,String[]> linesToArraysMap = new HashMap<Integer,String[]>();
        for(int i=1;i<=lines.size();i++) {
            linesToArraysMap.put(i, lines.get(i-1).split(","));
            //if you want to get them as ArrayLists you can do:
            //List<String> lineList = Arrays.asList(lines.get(i-1).split(","));
        }
        for(String[] stringArr:linesToArraysMap.values()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArr));
        }
    }
```